# How can I use a component template in any module or component?

Tags: angular

I have created a custom header that I want to import in several components.
eg:-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void { }

}
```

this is the component and I want to use it in a different component inside a different module. How can I import it in an HTML by using  selector. I want to use it as a reusable component. This component is imported in app.module.ts and every time I use the selector to import it in another module, I get this error.:

```
ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'app-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

I tried importing the header in the separate modules's module.ts but it gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You can't use like this.

If you want to use some shared component in more than one module you must have to create the module first for shared component and then Only you can use this component across modules.

Example - Create module for the single component `app.header.module.ts` then export your `app-header` component in that module and import `app.header.module.ts` Module in different modules then only you can use this as shared component.

Answer (score 1):

[Example Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular) After insert declarations in appmodule just put

```
<app-header></app-header> in parent component's html
```

and if you have any input in child in html

```
 <app-header [param_name]="param_value"></app-header>
```

in child component

```
@Input param_name:string//type of your variable
```